# How to build Dimensional model for commission received and return

Tags: dimensional-modeling, fact-table

I am working on the Insurance broker Dimensional model and we have Policy table and relevant other tables like Customer and  date table..

Now we are working for further to add some more fact and dimension table when we received commission from the insurance company when policy is sold and Commission returning to insurance Company when policy cancel.

So basically the Finance  Invoice billing Reporting  to reconcile with Different Insurance Providers.

Here is some sample data:

[image]

So How should we build the fact table and dimension table to track the
--How much amount we received for each Insurance which are linked to each policy
--How much amount we paid back Return to each Insurance which each policy is cancelled..

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what are you actually stuck on? Please update your question with what you’ve managed to design so far - as editable text, no pictures please

Comment: Hi Nick... 
We have already a Policy table in our model which has  policy details including the Expected Commission,  policy start date, policy cancel date etc...
now we need for Commission and refund fact table as i explained how can we design this new fact table grain. shall we keep the 2 separate fact tables : one fact table   for Commission received  transaction,   AND Another fact table for Commission returned.

Comment: OR we should have one single fact table to having 2 rows for each Policy Id  where 1  row is for Commission received and 2nd rows is for Commission returned and some sort of  payment  Type column to indicate where ( Payment Received, Payment Returned) .

We need to see the report against the billing statement we are getting from the each Insurance company

Answer (score 0):

You would follow the same process you would for any dimensional model:

From your business requirements:

- identify the measures
- identify the attributes required to slice/dice/aggregate the measures

The attributes give you your dimensions.

Determine the grain of your measures

If measures have the same grain then they can go into the same fact table.

If measures have a different grain then they must go into different fact tables